# Using typescript Exclude with generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A routine update of dependences in my TypeScript-based Nodejs project has caused me to receive TypeScript compilation errors in a generic class used to manage [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) models. I've narrowed the problem down to what seems to be an issue with TypeScript handling of generic types.

I've constructed the following minimal example:

```
interface I {
    p: string;
}

class Foo<T extends I> {
    exclude: Exclude<'p', 'q'> = 'p'; // OK
    excludeI: Exclude<keyof I, 'q'> = 'p'; // OK
    excludeT: Exclude<keyof T, 'q'> = 'p'; // TS2322: Type '"p"' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, "q">'.
}
```

Note that the only difference between the types of `excludeI` (which compiles fine) and `excludeT` (which fails to compile with the given error) is that the latter uses the generic type `T` rather than the interface type `I`.

As `T` is specified to extend `I`, I would expect these two lines to be treated identically. Indeed, it seems that the `keyof` operator has no problem working with them interchangeably:

```
class Foo<T extends I> {
    keyof: 'p' = 'p'; // OK
    keyofI: keyof I = 'p'; // OK
    keyofT: keyof T = 'p'; // OK
}
```

I have used [this example on the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4Chm%20QBwC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfLLUSWRFAKUxzwEdiyKIGvUYIANnBIlkAMQD2cgDwAVZBAAekEABNpqAHxc8yANYQAnnJjEA5PhvIAvMjs3qyAPQfkAeQDS3LhmljCoxMFWaE4u9u5evgHGETDK4RaRqs6ucd7%20jMbxYAAWwNKlyMUoAK4kKAiSKJTAAG5UBFByAEZiEAC2ZSDIALJyQgq1gWrq4lXaEMQAotNisxCKrgA0pukwyOyGWbGeuYl4GjNzYchLF2vJaFv3%209HZxwmT5ytzqdfLq4r3ZSPHZ7A4xNxvZQAZQATABmGEw4jKcz4FA2ABE%20AxDnKIDkYGQkhIwEoIDg3RQYDkFVR6JuXzuIKByAxPAx%20hsADpJpN4jU2hotLoidI0VBkMBevger0IOA4GBgKNkJEGatCB9NPLdLZ7FNhdInsgAPzIEAQZrQZBpELITLgnLvYxCnUkK73dCunRGkGcM0Wq0S20ZF5HeJ5F3an0-QEGt3bO3%2082W60h3YO17xaHwxHIukuLE4yXSfGE4mk8mUio0sAFmxx70itkY00poM2xMZbkiZBAA) to experiment with different TS versions, and it doesn't seem to be version-dependent behavior.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on with [Exclude<>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) here?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33484 This seems to in fact be an issue with typescript, not sure how to fix it though

Comment: Thanks for that link @AlexChashin, it certainly seems a closely-related if not identical problem. Still not sure how `keyof` could work as expected but then `Exclude` would not.

Comment: Note that in your playground example, your `extendsXX` types are not the same as the types using `Exclude`; the latter is a [distributive condtional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) but your `extendsXX` types are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of the TypeScript compiler.  It is not generally possible for the compiler to verify assignability of a value to a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) that depends on an unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type parameter.  In such cases the evaluation of the conditional type is *deferred* until the type parameter has been specified, and before this happens the type is more or less opaque to the compiler.

The [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) utility type is [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/6b04f5039429b9d412696fe2febe39ecc69ad365/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1494) as a conditional type like this:

```
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

And since `T` is a generic type parameter, then `Exclude<keyof T, 'p'>` is a conditional type depending on a generic type parameter.  Inside of the `Foo` class definition, `T` is unspecified, so you will tend to see somewhat unintelligent behavior from the compiler there.

---

This is the subject of several GitHub issues, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#33484](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33484) about `Omit` not recognizing such assignability (`Omit` is currently implemented with `Exclude`), or [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) about how `Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>` is not seen as assignable to `T`, or [microsoft/TypeScript#36737](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36737) about how you can't easily return values in a function returning a generic conditional type.

---

So, how can you proceed?  The right answer here is probably just to accept that you are smarter than the compiler and to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you are sure what you are doing is safe even though the compiler isn't:

```
excludeT = "p" as Exclude<keyof T, "p">; // okay
```

or, if you can get away with using a specific instead of a generic type, the compiler can reason more easily about that, as you've seen:

```
excludeI: Exclude<keyof I, 'q'> = 'p'; // OK
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4Chm+QBwC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfLLBAGzhJOQDEB7bgHgAqyCAA9IIACYdUAPkw48olgFcJEYgFERKtXwDk+PQBpkegI565AXlOHqyAPQPkAeQDSC3EuaqIqTdo+ugDWEACe3DBoJuaWyDYGevZOrh54woG+QjYARPg5yGzIWjoQfKERUQIxFjLJztzBcGHInsg5FZE5xInxtkmOzu5tnTD+yKNofYn1qSPhkQLEk9n9s8P0yEA)

Comment: I have, indeed, resorted to a type assertion for the actual problem encountered with Mongoose, though it took quite some time to unpack the various nested generics used internally by that library to figure out what type I should even _pretend_ to be using! I'm still not 100% sure why `keyof` should be "easier" for the compiler than `Exclude`, but you've given lots of useful info -- thanks!